# Retag request: [uinewsstand] -> [newsstand-kit]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Please retag [uinewsstand](/questions/tagged/uinewsstand) as [newsstand-kit](/questions/tagged/newsstand-kit)

The proper name for the iOS Newsstand framework is "Newsstand Kit". If necessary to disambiguate between the actual Newsstand APIs and the Newsstand app/store/platform, `ios-newsstand` can be used to refer to the ecosystem.

Neither are a part of `UIKit` and thus the `UI` prefix is a confusing misnomer.

Comment: It are only 2 questions, so just retagging should be easy. But why not `[newsstand-kit]`?

Comment: `newsstand-kit` is, indeed, a better name. Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

> It are only 2 questions, so just retagging should be easy.

It was very easy indeed.

You can thank / blame / ritually sacrifice me later, or something.